# Error with apache2 restart after sudo rm .conf file

Tags: apache2

I'd previously created a .conf file in /etc/apache2/sites-available called 'gs30D7.com.conf' and I'd run sudo a2ensite on it so I could use it. However I recently removed that file by running:

sudo rm gs30D7.com.conf but now apache won't restart and I get this error:

```
 * Restarting web server apache2                                         [fail] 
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
apache2: Syntax error on line 219 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not
 open configuration file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/gs30D7.com.conf: No 
such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

I looked in apache2.conf but see no reference to that file.

This is what shows up in the error log:

```
[Wed May 18 20:05:14.098788 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 10666] 
AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

you did not disable the site. hope this still works after you deleted it.

```
sudo a2dissite gs30D7.com.conf
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 force-reload
```

or

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```